# Error checking TLS connection with Docksal

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

I'm getting this error when trying to start Docksal machine with `fin up` or `fin vm start`

```
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs:
There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.64.100:2376": 
dial tcp 192.168.64.100:2376: getsockopt: connection refused 
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'. 
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which will stop running containers.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes docker-machine certificaties re-generation fails.

Usually it is solved with `fin vm restart`.

If simple restart did not help try:

```
fin docker-machine regenerate-certs -f
fin vm restart
```

However in rare cases this does not help too. If that does not help either you will have to delete existing Docksal VM and re-create it.

```
fin vm remove
fin system start
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this warrants its own answer. As [mentioned in the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348440/error-checking-tls-connection-with-docksal#comment75919903_42767815) Cisco AnyConnect is (possibly permanently) in conflict with Docker. [OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/index.html) is meant to be a drop-in replacement for AnyConnect and seems to work well.

I've tested this with docksal and it seems to be working. Process:

- Install OpenConnect and get connected
- `fin vm restart`
- `fin project restart`

That got things working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue - it was caused by being connected to a VPN. Try disconnecting from the VPN. ([Source](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/346#issuecomment-170232566))

Comment: Yes VPN is another headache.

Comment: Is there a way around the VPN issues? So that users can be connected to VPN and run docksal?

Comment: @Bratchley We use Cisco AnyConnect, and in my case there was an alternative, openconnect, which connects you to the VPN without messing with your network. See: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/628#issuecomment-197062382